# In app Biiling sample application integration

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am trying to integrate the sample "In App" billing application provided (Dungeons) by google to my application.

I have published my application in Android Market and created a product list which contains some products. Now I want to put these product IDs in my sample application in order to be able to buy the products.

But I don't know where to specify these product ID's in my application.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In Dungeons.java file search for "CatalogEntry"

```
 private static final CatalogEntry[] CATALOG = new CatalogEntry[] {
        new CatalogEntry("sword_001", R.string.two_handed_sword, Managed.MANAGED),
        new CatalogEntry("potion_001", R.string.potions, Managed.UNMANAGED),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.purchased", R.string.android_test_purchased,
                Managed.UNMANAGED),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.canceled", R.string.android_test_canceled,
                Managed.UNMANAGED),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.refunded", R.string.android_test_refunded,
                Managed.UNMANAGED),
        new CatalogEntry("android.test.item_unavailable", R.string.android_test_item_unavailable,
                Managed.UNMANAGED),
    };
```